# How to show label with line and display label outside in piechart in extjs4.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, sencha-architect, extjs4.2

can anybody tell How to show label with line and display label outside in extjs4.1.I want to display label outside of pie and show line to map the label

```
eg 

     /   \      \   
    test  test1  test2
```

Comment: @rixo can u help in this

Answer (score 1):

You've got the [`display` option of the `label` config](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.chart.Label-cfg-label), that you can set to 'outside'.

As for the lines, you'll have to draw them yourself... Which would be a quite involved hack IMO. If you're interested in trying, that takes place in [`Ext.chart.Label#renderLabels()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/source/Label.html#Ext-chart-Label-method-renderLabels), and uses [`Ext.chart.series.Pie`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/source/Pie.html#Ext-chart-series-Pie)'s `onCreateLabel()` and `onPlaceLabel()` methods. Don't forget to take your trigonometry with you before diving in there!